# How to place a 2D text layer over a Three.js scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created a simple 3D scene written in JavaScript. The scene renders a `THREE.SphereGeometry` with a `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial`. The only thing I need is a text layer located over `Three.js` scene.

**`Question`: How to place a 2D text over rendered Three.js scene?**

```javascript
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First page.</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link href="/errordocs/style/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">            
        <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
 
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            var scene, camera, renderer;
            var geometry, material, mesh;

            init();

            function init() {                    
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x222222 );
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 100 );
                camera.position.z = 1;

                geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.1, 20, 20 );
                material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( mesh );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, sorry, I thought that was your problem, that the code does not work. My mistake. Feel free to revert it back if you want, or even better → make it work. An executable snippet is a good way to get more answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is more than one way to achieve the intended result.

1. For most cases, using [THREE.CSS2DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer) as a label or annotation renderer gives proper results. The good thing is that you can easily style your texts with CSS. The renderer is used e.g. in this example: https://threejs.org/examples/css2d_label
2. Another way is to render text on a canvas and then use it as a texture for an instance of [THREE.Sprite](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Sprite). Using sprites makes it possible to blend or hide labels behind other 3D objects which does not work with a HTML/CSS based solution.
3. I know you specifically asked for 2D text but for 3D text you could use [TextGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/TextGeometry) to generate a mesh.

Answer (score 2):

I've chosen [THREE.TextSprite](https://github.com/SeregPie/THREE.TextSprite) solution. It's as simple as that:

```js
import TextSprite from '@seregpie/three.text-sprite';

let sprite = new THREE.TextSprite( {
                               text: 'Text must be rendered here...',
                          alignment: 'center'
                         fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                           fontSize: 28,
                              color: '#ffffff' } );
 
scene.add( sprite );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `React`, you can use the `Text` component from `@react-three/drei`

```
import { Text } from '@react-three/drei'
```

```
<Text
  scale={[4, 4, 4]}
  color="black"
  anchorX="center" 
  anchorY="bottom" 
  position={[0, 0, 0]}
  rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
>
  Your Text
</Text>
```

Comment: Note: this only works with React on the web, NOT with React Native.